# S3 PutObject returns AccessDenied for PutObject command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Hoping someone can help.

Having an issue trying to write to an S3 bucket in a different account.

- Myself and others have gone over the role (sts assumed) and the
  permissions appear to be correct.
- The bucket is encrypted with KMS
- ListObjects returns a successful response.
- CloudTrail shows the KMS
  key being generated so we are getting to the bucket and kms is
  allowing encryption.
- CloudTrail shows the role being assumed.

I am not sure if the request is correct

```
PutObjectCommandInput
{
    "middlewareStack": {},
    "input": {
      "Bucket": "com-a-bucket-dev-feeds",
      "Body": "{ "value": "success"}",
      "Key": "datalake/raw/sites/20220127153225490.9CBC8C6F00DF025CE053AC17050DAF8F.json"
    }
  }
```

The error response is:

> AccessDenied: Access Denied
> at deserializeAws_restXmlPutObjectCommandError (/var/task/app.js:31983:43)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async /var/task/app.js:7648:24
> at async /var/task/app.js:14753:22
> at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/task/app.js:13621:42)
> at async /var/task/app.js:13258:24 {
> Code: 'AccessDenied',

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's better to provide what have you done. How have you provided access. What permissions have you given to the role. How have you given cross account access. It will help understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "IAM Policy Simulator" to validate your access.

https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

[image: the policy simulator]

Answer (score 0):

After some digging with AWS Support, we discovered the issue.
The role policy in the second account was checking that the source of the action was from the VPC in which the Lambda was attached. This information is lost when the Lambda assumed a role in the second account, the AWS VPC for Lambdas is what was seen during the role policy check. ListObjects worked because a separate statement allowed it without a check for a specific VPC.

Changing the statement fixed the issue.

A few things to note about the request for cross-account access:

- Bucket is the bucket name, not the ARN
- The Key should not begin with a "/"
- Leaving out the KMS/ACL information in the request will default to using what is defined on the bucket.

Thanks for the suggestions and hopes this helps someone.